# Which Radeon HD 5770 Driver should I install?

Tags: windows-7, amd-radeon

I cant find my RADEON HD 5770 driver. My OS is Windows 7 64 bit. It are Desktop Graphics.

Is this the correct one: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx

Or this: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/integrated_vista64.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.43&lang=us&rev=&ostype=Windows%207%20-%2064-Bit%20Edition

Or this: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_vista64.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.43&lang=us&rev=&ostype=Windows%207%20-%2064-Bit%20Edition#1

Or this: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/raid_windows.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.43&lang=us&rev=&ostype=Windows%207%20-%2064-Bit%20Edition

Answer (score 1):

Definitely not the last one. From the other's it doesn't mattter which one you pick as they are the same...

Comment: Should I install the AMD Profile thing first or the things in Optional  tabs first after then Catalyst

Comment: The profiles are just to support applications, best to install those after the drivers, the same counts for other optional things. So, just install the drivers and only install extra things if you actually need them.